# recompile with -xlint: unchecked/unsafe operations

Tags: java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class DisplayingText extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Text text = new Text();

        text.setFont(new Font(45));

        text.setX(50);
        text.setY(50);

        text.setText("Welcome my friend!");

        Group root = new Group();

        ObservableList list = root.getChildren();

        list.add(text);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);

        stage.setTitle("Sample Application");

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The compiler says I am using something not something. Here's what the compiler says:

> C:\Users\Resul\Desktop\Skills\For Java>javac -Xlint:unchecked DisplayingText.jav a
> DisplayingText.java:25: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a membe r of the raw type List
> list.add(text);
> where E is a type-variable:
> E extends Object declared in interface List 1 warning
> C:\Users\Resul\Desktop\Skills For Java>

Since I don't know English well, I translated everything the compiler said. But still, I didn't understand what exactly the compiler wants. because it's the first time I'm facing this.

Comment: The type of root.getChildren() is ObservableList<Node>. You used ObservableList - which is called raw generic - raw means you did not specify the type of item in the list. Raw generics exist for compatibility with java 1.4, which did not have generics at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The warning is telling you that the parameter passed to `add` is unknown type (not compile time checked). This would be fixed if you use the proper return type of `root.getChildren()` which  is declared as:

```
 ObservableList<Node> list = root.getChildren();
```

After this change, any attempt to add something that isn't a`Node` would be spotted by the compiler.

Comment: Hi DunkG! Thank you for answering. I checked your version, but the compiler now claims that there is an error here. ---`C:\Users\Resul\Desktop\Skills For Java>javac DisplayingText.java DisplayingText.java:23: error: ';' expected ObservableList<Node> list.getChildren();
1 error`---

Comment: @ResulHaydarmyradov Reload the page, I made a mistake in the declaration of `list`

Comment: Now the Compiler says: 
`C:\Users\Resul\Desktop\Skills For Java javac DisplayingText.java DisplayingText.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
ObservableList<Node> list = root.getChildren();
symbol: class Node location: class DisplayingText
error
1` The compiler points to the word <Node>

Comment: You need to `import javafx.scene.Node;` too